# PHP Curl POST/SESSION/COOKIE Issue

Tags: php, post, curl

I want to create a script that can login using POST info, then browses through afew pages, on the same time. (After logging in) So I need to keep the session/cookie thing...

I've tried afew things, the logging in (POST) works fine.

But when I try to execute a second url, (the first being the login page) I lose the session/cookie and it the webpage says i'm no longer logged in:

Where am I going wrong with my code?

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/authenticate.php';
$url2 = 'http://www.example.com/twourl.php';

$player = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypass';
$fields = array(
            'player'=>urlencode($player),
            'password'=>urlencode($password),
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//execute post
curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//execute two url
curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Why is it not keeping me logged in on the second url?

Comment: I think we need to see your code for authenticate.php.

Comment: Well it's a third party website, so I guess I cannot.

Comment: @Steven Tilling i'm trying to do the same thing, have you figured it out? If so, can you post the answer? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php#97160 I don't see where you are trying to pass the session to the site.

EDIT: you can also check out http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10346748

Comment: I didn't know I had to do a sessions thing, i thought the same connection = same session. Thanks i'll look into it.